# Example of functions where L'Hospital fails with limit at finite value due to nonexistence of limits of derivatives but the actual limit exists.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I've seen that L'Hospital's Rule fails for functions such as

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{x+\sin(x)}$$

since the limit of the derivatives oscillates. But all the examples I've seen so far have been limits at infinity. Are there any examples of functions where the actual limit exists, the limit is evaluated at a finite value but the limit of the derivatives is not equal to the actual limit?

I've been thinking about the functions $f(x)=1/x+\sin(1/x)$ and $g(x)=1/x$ and taking the limit as $x\to 0$ but clearly these functions are not differentiable at an interval containing zero so it doesn't work.

Comment: Hospital rule does not require that the functions are differentiable at the limit point but that the limit of the ratio of the derivatives exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $$\lim_{x\to 0}{f(x)\over g(x)},\quad \, g(x)=x+\sin x,\ f(x)=\begin{cases} x^2\sin{1\over x} & x\neq 0\\
0 & x=0
\end{cases}$$
The limit is equal $0.$ Both functions $f$ and $g$ are differentiable for any $x$ including $0.$ We have $f'(0)=0$ and
$$f'(x)=2x\sin{1\over x}-\cos{1\over x},\quad x\neq 0,\quad
g'(x)=1+\cos x$$
Therefore  $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}{f'(x)\over g'(x)}$ does not
exist.

Comment: You can more simply take $g(x)=x$.

Comment: @egreg I have chosen $x+\sin x$ intentionally to avoid the  immediate reduction to $x\sin{1\over x}.$